# Atomic transaction for WCF service and local database

Tags: wcf, transactions

I want to wrap a WCF external web service call and and a local database call (nhibernate) in one atomic transaction.

Is this even possible?

At the moment I am doing the following:

1. Perform update on local database.
2. Perform update on web service.
3. If web service call is successful commit local changes to database.

But what happens if it fails on commit?

Comment: Is the external service also WCF?

Comment: Yes the external service is also WCF.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by *external web service* you mean a service which is exposed across the public web.

If the external service supports [WS-Atomic Transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729784%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then yes it's possible to propagate a local transaction across to the service.

However, it's questionable if this approach is wise, unless the external service is also wcf over wsHttpBinding.

If the external service is non-wcf then it's likely that there will be considerable pain involved in integration; although WS-AT is designed for inter-operability, in practice there will almost certainly be variation in how the protocol has been interpreted by the different vendors, which could lead to the client and service being effectively non-inter-operable.

> But what happens if it fails on commit?

As an alternative solution I would consider a [compensatory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensation_(engineering)) pattern for this problem. As an example:

1. Update DB
2. Call service
3. If service call success, commit DB
4. If service call failure, do not commit DB

The benefit here is that system consistency can be provided in a single place. However, your problem now becomes how to tell if the call was successful or not.

Unfortunately, when you make a service call it's always possible for the call to return failure but actually succeed. A good example of this is service time-out.

How do you actually tell if you call failed? The only way is to perform a lookup against the remote resource to work out if the state of the system includes your update.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-) have you got an example of how I go about using a WS-Atomic Transaction?

Comment: Are you in control of the external service? Do you know that it has been configured to support WS-AT? When you say *external* service do you mean it's not on the LAN? Across the public web?

Comment: The reason I ask is there's a much simpler solution if you don't have to go outside the LAN

Comment: Yes I am in control of the external service. I can configure it to support WS-AT I just need some guidance. 

It's not on the LAN :( it will be across the public web.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733943(v=vs.110).aspx. It's not what I would call trivial. A colleague of mine set a transactional endpoint up a few years ago and said it was a nightmare and not to do it.

Comment: Yeah I was just reading that article but was hoping for something a little more simple. That looks like an absolute nightmare and probably not worth the effort to be honest. I will have a think about it and see if its worth implementing. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In regards to the compensation pattern you described above. What happens if there is an error when committing to the database? The service call needs to then be rolled back as well :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70570/discussion-between-user2909756-and-tom-redfern).